# ThreadingPool Dynamic Worker Count

Tags: python, concurrency, threadpool, concurrent.futures

I'm still working on my project. I want to adjust worker count dynamically. So, there is the psuedo-code:

```
while active_request:
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    executor.submit(my_func, (my_params)))
```

My active request sometimes 5 or 30 count. So uncertain. I want to execute `my_func` function concurrently,  but this code after 5 or 6 time execute, and stop the creating threads. I will wait suggestions of you.

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information for anyone to respond.

Comment: Just specify a `max_workers` argument big enough for the worst case—only the number needed at any one time will be used.

Comment: @martineau thanks for your reply, but ThreadPool kill threads after work and don't create any thread, because max_workers count exceed border. I want after one thread killed, another thread created by ThreadPool.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about that, plus a `ThreadPoolExecutor` will reuse idle worker threads before starting *`max_worker`* threads (according to its documentation).

Comment: @martineau but situation not this. I observing threads on the Task Manager, after reached maximum threads number, workers not used again. As if threads enter the deadlock. But I don't see any thread, except main worker thread.

Comment: You can't tell from the Task Manger whether threads are being reused—only the maximum number of them at best.

Comment: @martineau If don't exist any threads, what thread can used by ThreadPool?

Comment: I think you are confusing threads with processes. You can only see processes in the Task Manager.

Comment: @martineau When I say Task Manager, actually I mentioned Process Hacker. When I look threads, problem is LdrAccessResource section. Probably my threads falling deadlock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228434/discussion-between-crazy-programmer-and-martineau).